# Saving Image Using firebase Url to gallery ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, firebase-storage

I'm developing ionic 3 app which can download images from firebase.
images can download successfully by giving the url.

By giving a regular link to image like [this](http://deportivate.com/wp-content/uploads/revslider/home-demo/sample-image-white.png)

the image will be download.This is working.

but if i give a firebase storage url 
like https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapp.appspot.com/o/1.jpg?alt=media&token=xxx

it won't download.In console i can see the image path and when i click it will open in browser.but when i run it on android it will not download.

How can i fix this?

my code for the download

```
download()
{
 var url =  'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapp.appspot.com/o/1.jpg?alt=media&token=ea450d47-b12c-4bcc-9e35-c2aba22bc155'
      var album = 'MyAppName';
      this.photoLibrary.saveImage(url,album).then((entry=>{
        console.log('download complete: ' + entry.photoURL);
        this.presentToast('download complete:' + entry.photoURL);
      }),
      (error) => {
        // handle error
        this.presentToast(error);
        this.loader.dismiss();
      });
}
```

I just found that tokens are downloading but not images

Comment: please provide the code snippet so we can help you

Comment: @Amr.Ayoub Done

Comment: what is this.photoLibrary.saveImage function ?
please post the code for it too

Comment: its a Plugin for saving images not a fuction https://github.com/terikon/cordova-plugin-photo-library

Comment: you need to store the image on your firebase storage first .
if you need an example on how to upload the picture then display it , let me know

Comment: I already store the pictures and made rules public also.The prblem is why i'm getting tokens not the images

Answer (score 1):

First you need to store your images on firebase ,change "MyImage" to your firebase storage.
then get the url and save the image on album by calling saveToAlbum function

```
getImage(image: string) {
     try {
         this.firebase.storage().ref().child("/myImages/" + image).getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
             this.saveToAlbum(url)
         });
     } catch (e) {
         console.log(e);
     }
 }


saveToAlbum(url){
let album = 'MyAppName';
  this.photoLibrary.saveImage(url,album).then((entry=>{
    console.log('download complete: ' + entry.photoURL);
    this.presentToast('download complete:' + entry.photoURL);
  }),
  (error) => {
    // handle error
    this.presentToast(error);
    this.loader.dismiss();
  });
```

}

Comment: Thank You this is also do the same thing in a properway. I found the problem  it will download the whole url as a file.I manually clear the file name without the image name now its showing. Is there any way to clearout the token things in firebase??